# CPU Benchmark - Set Load, usage spikes

Tags: central-processing-unit, benchmark

I need a CPU benchmark to test the performance impact of various power management policies. I must be able to set the load (e.g. to get a relatively steady load of 20%-30%-60%) and to simulate usage spikes (set frequency of spikes). I would also like it to be scriptable so as to be able to change benchmark settings in an indirect manner. I will be using Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the operating system you wish to perform these tests would be helpful :)
For stress testing the cpu you could use :
http://www.fossiltoys.com/cpuload.html

Also you could check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141707/how-to-set-cpu-load-on-a-redhat-linux-box